# Dynamic dataframe column name in apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the current dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':[1111,1111,2222,3333,4444,4444,5555,6666],
                   'columnB':['AAAA','AAAA','BBBB','AAAA','BBBB','BBBB','AAAA','BBBB'],
                   'columnC':['one','two','one','one','one','sales','two','one'],
                   'NUM1':[1,3,5,7,1,0,4,5],
                   'NUM2':[5,3,6,9,2,4,1,1],
                   'W':list('aaabbbbb')})
```

and I am trying to use a dynamic column in the following code:

```
#First aggregate the data
d = {'columnB':'unique', 'columnC':'unique' }
df2 = df.groupby('columnA').agg(d)


#Convert list to string for each cell of the inventory field
mylist = ["columnB","columnC"]
for x in mylist:
    columnName = x
    #print("df2."+columnName+".apply(', '.join)")
    df2[columnName] = df2[columnName].apply(', '.join)
```

and it works fine in Jupyter. My issue is that it does not work when I run it on visualstudio. I am getting this error:

> sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

after print the dataframe's type I am getting this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Here is the full error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "stage1.py", line 112, in  main() File "stage1.py", line 57, in main templateScenarios[columnName] = templateScenarios[columnName].apply(', '.join) File "/Users/apolo.siskos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2355, in apply mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype) File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1574, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: which versions of python and pandas are each of your interpreters using?

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: @PaulH Python 3.6.3 and Pandas 0.20.3

Comment: in *both*? are you sure?

Comment: @PaulH Yes. I typed python3 in the console and got the first one. I printed this in my script: `pd.__version__` and got the second one.

Comment: Here is the full error message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stage1.py", line 112, in <module>
    main()
  File "stage1.py", line 57, in main
    templateScenarios[columnName] = templateScenarios[columnName].apply(', '.join)
  File "/Users/apolo.siskos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2355, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1574, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: Have you considered working in a text editor and terminal rather than an IDE?

Comment: I'm asking if you're sure that jupyter and VS are talking to the same python interpreter

Comment: @PaulH In Jupyter I just pasted the dataframe. It is not connected to the VS. Considering that the type is dataframe, why isn't my code working?

Comment: I think your jupyter instance and your VS instance are talking to different python interpreters. Your code and other, equivalent versions of it work fine for me.

Comment: @PaulH It should work find in VS. It probably has to do with the dataframe. When I print the df2[columnName] I am getting this: 
`64956          [one]
64988          [two]
65036          [nan]`

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, that would be the problem: `nan` would be considered a `float` and you will see an error when trying to join strings with floats.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I tried fillna() though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem `NaN`s values, so is possible remove them by `dropna` and use custom function with `join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':[1111,1111,2222,3333,4444,4444,5555,6666],
                   'columnB':[np.nan,np.nan,'BBBB','AAAA','BBBB','BBBB','AAAA','BBBB'],
                   'columnC':['one','two','one','one','one','sales','two','one'],
                   'NUM1':[1,3,5,7,1,0,4,5],
                   'NUM2':[5,3,6,9,2,4,1,1],
                   'W':list('aaabbbbb')})

f = lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().unique())
d = {'columnB': f, 'columnC':f}
df2 = df.groupby('columnA').agg(d)
print (df2)
        columnB     columnC
columnA                    
1111               one, two
2222       BBBB         one
3333       AAAA         one
4444       BBBB  one, sales
5555       AAAA         two
6666       BBBB         one
```

Comment: Why didn't this cover me though? `df2 = df2.fillna('none')`

Comment: It replace `NaN` or `None` to string `none`. your solution should working, but it is not missing values, only string.

Comment: A previous question I had, returned lists in every cell. That is why I tried the solution above. Now, with your x.dropna() I no longer need it :) Thanks.

Comment: You are wlcome!

Comment: Why does it convert it into a list? I might raise a different question on that although it is simple.

Comment: `unique` return `np.array`, so is necessary `join`.